# How to fix error: invalid value 'f95' in '-x f95'?

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, ide

I'm using Fortran with CodeBlocks IDE, and when I try to build my code I get this error

```
error: invalid value 'f95' in '-x f95'
```

and after that there is no executable file. The thing is, when I write in the 
terminal

```
gfortran nameofmyfile.f
```

I get the correct executable file "a.out".

**Question:** How can I fix this problem?

Especifications: I have mac OS X 10.8.5, installed xcode, gcc, and gfortran.

Comment: Though I have never used CodeBlocks up to now, isn't it that the compiler used by CodeBlocks points to /usr/bin/gcc (or clang)? It gives such an error on my computer (OSX 10.9). If I use /usr/local/bin/gcc-5 (e.g., installed by homebrew), it gives no error.

Comment: @roygvib I just changed the directory to /usr/local/bin but when I try to compile, it does absolutely nothing. The error doesn't show, though.

Comment: Hmm, I tried installing CodeBlocks, but it doesn't work for me (nor even boot) for some reasons... But generally speaking, we usually have some preference tab like "Menu -> Compiler... -> Toolchain excutable" in which we can choose compilers (GCC vs clang etc, with options). Things may work if you can point your compiler to /usr/local/bin/gcc-5 etc, but since I cannot test this myself, I hope someone will show more useful info...

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE uses the clang compiler which does not support Fortran.
See also https://answers.launchpad.net/mg5amcnlo/+question/698961 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70010.